# HTML/CSS - position:fixed prevents scroll bar from appearing on minimised screen

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS and whilst playing around with web design found a *very* annoying issue - I am trying to create a fixed header (to make a navigation bar) but...

**When the screen is minimised with the position:fixed property value pair in CSS, the horizontal scroll bar does not appear.**

To see what I mean, take a look at the code below: opening the html as it is and minimising your browser would create a horizontal scroll bar just fine, but take away the /* */ comment signs in the CSS and all of a sudden this scroll bar stops appearing and all hell breaks loose with positioning.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    min-width:1000px;
}
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    /* position:fixed; */
}
```

Any help on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks,

Philip.

Comment: Its not a issue, this is how position fixed works. Can you post fiddle or codepen demo of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to get a scroll bar visible when I minimise my browser, but whilst I have my div position:fixed in CSS, I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you need horizontal scroll always: just add `overflow-x: scroll;` to `body` in css.
or you may specify sizes of the screen when it is on with `@media`:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work as the scroll bar is locked, but maybe I am just doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position:fixed` in a container, the whole container is taken out of the normal flow. So the things that normally affect elements in the normal flow will not affect it. (The `absolute` positioning behaves the same way, by the way). I tweaked your code a bit so you can see this. Try playing around with it, and hopefully you'll see something. Try uncommenting `position:fixed` in CSS, then the new `div` in HTML, and then `top:100px` (this pushes the `div` 100px downward) in CSS.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div class="header">I am the header.</div>

    <!-- <div>
        <p>I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div. I am a paragraph in another div.</p>
    </div> -->
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
min-width:1000px;
color: green;
}
.header {
color: orange;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
/*position:fixed;*/
/*top: 100px;*/

}
```

Comment: I have tried this and although it does enables me to scroll horizontally when minimised, the fixed header is fixed horizontally, this is to say that scrolling left to right 'I am the header' is always visible on the left of the screen - is there some way to prevent this horizontal fix as ideally the header would be fixed vertically, but I could scroll through its contents horizontally, i.e. the 'I am the header' text would move out of view when I scrolled right with the browser minimised.

Comment: ***EDIT***: What I'm trying to say is this works, but is there a way to make the position:fixed on only one axis? So that when someone scrolls up and down the position is fixed but when someone scrolls from side to side they scroll through the div. Thanks

Comment: It seems that the `fixed` positioning 'disables' the scrolling ability in all directions (that's why you could not scroll horizontally when you had only one `div` with the `position:fixed` applied to it at the beginning).So it is literally fixed in all directions and the only way you can move it is by using properties such as `left`/`right` and `top`/`bottom`. Are you trying to do something with it or are you just curious? Note that, had the text in your header been longer, you wouldn't need to scroll horizontally to see the whole thing.